# MembershipUser.TryParse()

Tags: .net, asp.net, tryparse

Anyone know an equiv?

Currently I'm doing..

```
Dim myUsers As New MembershipUserCollection
Dim myUser As MembershipUser
Dim RoleUsers() As String
RoleUsers = Roles.GetUsersInRole("User")

For Each x As String In RoleUsers
    Dim roleUser As MembershipUser
    roleUser = Membership.GetUser(x)
    If Not roleUser Is Nothing Then
        myUsers.Add(Membership.GetUser(x))
    End If
Next
```

Just wondering if there's something like..

```
If MembershipUser.TryParse(Membership.GetUser(x),myUser) Then
    myUsers.Add(myUser)
End If
```

VB or C# works.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What would you want a TryParse method to do ?

Comment: I like the simplicity of TryParse() with an OUT.

Comment: Erm... could you maybe stretch that out a bit?  What are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is no method (neither in Roles nor in MembershipUser ) that deals with class instead of string name. 
So may be there is a sense in direct SQL to database (in case of SqlMembershipProvider usage).

Using LINQ makes your code more elegant but doesn't resolve performance issue.